# Disabling a dynamic HTML element with condition using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following two html elements

```html
<div class="col-sm">
  <label for="numberOfShiftPerDay">Number of Shift Per Day</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numberOfShiftPerDay" name="numberOfShiftPerDay" placeholder="No: of Shift Per Day" title="Please key in how many number of shift per day" min="1" max="4">
</div>
```

The second element is created using some php for loops

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <?php
        for($loop = 1; $loop<=4; $loop++){
            echo '<div class="col-sm">
                      <label>Shift '.$loop.' Duration</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="shift'.$loop.'Duration" name="shift'.$loop.'Duration">
                            <option>8</option>
                            <option>12</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>';
        }            
     ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What I Need**

I need the second element disable based on some conditions when someone change the first option element. Thus I have written the following JQuery

```js
$("#numberOfShiftPerDay").change(function() {
  if ($("#numberOfShiftPerDay").html == "1") {
    $("#shift1Duration").attr("disabled");
  }

});
```

But somehow it is not disabling. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery method "val()" to fetch the 'text' in the input, not the html(). Then you can use either one of the following ways to disable the "input" on value change.

```
$("#numberOfShiftPerDay").change(function() { 
   $(this).attr('disabled', $(this).val() == "1");
});
```

**OR**

```
$("#numberOfShiftPerDay").change(function() { 
   $(this).prop('disabled', $(this).val() == "1");
});
```

Comment: Thank you Murali. But just a side note question. If i disabled an input div, can I still grab the value of that input div using JQuery or form submit ($_POST) method?

Comment: @ Yes, even if the "input" is disabled, you can read it's value.